# HTML Snippet code WebPart "Find by Document ID" gives an error "One of the properties of the Web Part has an incorrect format"

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout, custom-masterpage, design-manager, snippet

I want to add web part to my custom  home.aspx site, and when i put the code generated from Design Manager HTML snippets i get an error saying:

One of the properties of the Web Part has an incorrect format. Microsoft SharePoint Foundation cannot deserialize the Web Part.  Check the format of the properties and try again.

I dident change or modify any properties yet, but i cant figure out whats wrong with the web part code.

Code for the webpart looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet generated by designer manager used for custom page layout/master page.

If you want to add the web part to a existing 'home.aspx', click site settings->edit page->add a web part
[image]